# How to delete a .metadata file

Tags: java, file

I have three different files with three different extensions: .resp, .req and .metadata. Doing a

```
    File file = new File(filename);
    file.delete();
```

will only work for the .resp and .resp files. How can I delete the .metadata file with java code.

Comment: What happens when you try to delete the files using command line or file browser? Are you sure the permissions allow deleting all files?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it fails? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path- instead, and you'll have an exception explaining what the problem is.

Comment: @Mureinik there's no exception. The file is still there at the file path. The others are gone.

Comment: @GhostCat before I delete the .metadata file from the file browser I have to stop the java processes running in the task manager or else I'll get a "The action can

Comment: @GhostCat can't be completed because the file is open in Java(TM) Platform SE binary"

Comment: Don't use Windows?

Comment: @chrylis I have to?

Comment: @JBNizet How is that supposed to help? I know what the method does...

Comment: You're wondering why File.delete doesn't delete the file and just fails silently. Hence my comment: if you use Files.delete() instead of File.delete(), you'll have an exception instead of a silent failure, and the exception will tell you what the problem is when deleting the file.

Comment: @JBNizet got it. I misunderstood. Thank you.